# How to know the size of GIT and SVN repository using shell script?

Tags: git, shell, svn, repository

I am trying to write a `shell script`, from which i can get to know the size of remote `GIT` repository and `SVN` repository.

Example:

```
My GIT repository 
name : MyGITProject
Username : MMMMM
password : yyyyy



My SVN repository
name : MySVNProject
Username : SSSSSSS
password : kkkkkk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git-sizer` for this purpose. [Here](https://blog.github.com/2018-03-05-measuring-the-many-sizes-of-a-git-repository/) it has been explained completely on how to do this process. Note that you need a local copy of your git to be able to do so.

To make it as a shell script:

1. Make a local copy of your git repository.
2. Change directory to there, run `git-sizer` in you shell
3. Echo the output to a file, you can strip the output to only give you the information you need.

Also, as a pure-shell workaround for SVN, I did this :

1. Update SVN
2. Run `du` recursively for the folders you need: `du -sh --max-depth=x` (X the depth of folder structure)

Technically, this is not a good idea to put `max-depth` to a high number. As your SVN might have astronomical number of files and folders in and this will bring a substantial overhead to your I/O and CPU. But it can help you write a useful script.

Comment: How to do it in remote repository ?

Comment: If you have shell access, then you can do the above on the remote shell. Of course, you will need to download and install `git-sizer` in the remote machine.